# Element Plus Problem el-table-infinite-scroll Issue (version 3.0.1)

Tags: scroll, vuejs3, nuxt3, element-plus

I have a small issue with el-table-infinite-scroll.
The problem is that, scrolling is not working when the table height less than 95px.
[Please check image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZbTi.png)

I tried several ways to solve but still scrolling is not working when the height of table less than 95px.
Please check the description and image in order to understand the issue in detail. Cheers!

Comment: using the example from the library's docs works fine with small table height, see this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/crimson-voice-m67bb5?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue).  Trim your table down to just the bare basics and then add customizations back one at a time and see if there's something causing it to break.  I would make an attempt but I'm not going to transcribe your image code by hand.  One of the reasons [why you shouldn't upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6225326)